# Odd Autocomplete + Password Remembering Behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, autocomplete, google-chrome

I'm having a hard time figuring out how Firefox and Chrome determining what fields are for a password and how they autocomplete them on other forms.

For my login form, I have this:

```
<p>
    <label for="login_email">Email:</label><br />
    <input id="login_email" name="login[email]" size="30" type="text">
</p>

<p>
    <label for="login_password">Password:</label><br />
    <input id="login_password" name="login[password]" size="30" type="password">
    <input id="login_password_hash" name="login[password_hash]" type="hidden">
</p>

<p>
    <input id="login_submit" value="LOGIN" type="submit">
</p>
```

The `login_password_hash` field is for hashing the password on client side before sending using Javascript, having Javascript disabled does not change the outcome.

And for creating a new user, I have this form:

```
<p>
    <label for="user_email">Email:</label>
    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="user_first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text">

</p>
<p>
    <label for="user_last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="user_password">Password:</label>
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password">
    <input id="user_password_hash" name="user[password_hash]" type="hidden">
</p>

<p><input id="user_submit" value="Create User" type="submit"></p>
```

Now after saving the password from the login form and visiting the new user form, the saved email is put in the last field before the password field and puts the password in the password field.

This happens on Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer. Any ideas on why Firefox and Chrome behave this way? The two forms have nothing in common, the names and ids are all different.

Comment: Why would you hash the password and then send the clear text password?

Comment: It doesn't, the password field is emptied before sending. The server checks for password_hash and if it's empty, will hashing the plain text since Javascript wasn't enabled.

Comment: But why have the field at all.  By allowing the client to submit a pre-hashed version, you are lessening your security.  If someone gets a hold of your database, they can simply submit the already hashed password they obtain from the database.

Comment: That is a good point, I should hash it again. Or should I not be that concerned about transmitting the password in plain text?

Comment: Relay the submitting to javascript: **Step1** User accesses your login page and receives a randomly generated string which is saved in a session variable. **Step2** User inputs his credentials into the username and password fields and triggers the javascript function by pressing the login button. **Step3** Javascript hashes the password, grabs the string (salt) in the session variable, adds it to the hashed password and hashes it again. **Step4** Javascript sends the username and the hashed salted password to your server.

Comment: **Step5** Server grabs the hashed password from your database (dont store plain text passwords in the database) based on the username the javascript sent, adds the salt from the users session variable, hashes it and compares it with the hashed salted password that javascript sent him. If they match everything is ok and the user logs in. _(NOTE: Don't forget to sanitize the inputs though)_ This way the database doesn't know your password yet knows your password is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that changing name and id attributes has no effect on the password managers in Firefox and Chrome, all they see is a password_field and the field above it and that is good enough for them.

So I'm just making the password field in create a new user as a text field.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1854

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable autocomplete on an input, try using the autocomplete attribute, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
```

This is not guaranteed to work in all browsers, however.

Comment: I want autocomplete for the login page, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well all browsers are going to pick up the most obvious field names:

- firstname
- lastname
- username
- password

And the obvious alternates of those (underscores for spaces, and some shorthand such as "user" and "pass" maybe).  It's going to be up to the browser itself and what version of it as to what crazy alternates are supported.

Comment: Changing both the id and name attributes on both email and password fields to complete gibberish still has Firefox and Chrome autocomplete both forms.